# what is required to get intellisense for Gtkmm using editor Geany!

Tags: c++, linux, intellisense, gtkmm, geany

i want to get the intellisense in GTkmm application, similarly as we get in dot net under windows. However this time i am using Linux, C++, Gtkmm and Geany as my editor. Please guide how to get the intellisense. Moreover, if any kind of editor supports the property of intellisense, please mention that also.

Thanks and Regards
Owais Masood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geany automatically indexes your open files for auto-completion, but if you want it to index some library or API, you have to create a global tags file like it describes [here](http://www.geany.org/manual/dev/index.html#global-tags) in the documentation.  I have had mixed results getting this to work completely and correctly though.

I used to use Geany on Linux, but I have moved to [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/developer-tools).  Even though it has an emphasis on Qt, you can use it on any C or C++ project (you just have to specify your own build process or do it outside the IDE).  The editor is one of the best I've used on Linux and the autocompletion works great without a whole lot of configuration.  Also check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator/2752396#2752396) on how to set the include paths.  Anything in the include paths will be indexed for autocompletion automatically.