# Missing include when compiling QT with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, command-line, include

I try to compile QT 5.0.0 in the command prompt of Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7, 64bit. The process itself is known and described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010) and [here](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/). On my machine, compilation stops because the compiler does not find a file:

```
 fatal error C1083: [..] "GLES2/gl2.h": No such file or directory
```

I found that missing file in a subdirectory of `C:\QTSources` - the folder in which I try to build the sources.

I added the line `INCLUDEPATH += "C:/QTSources/qtwebkit/Source/ThirdParty/ANGLE/include"` to the file *qtsdk.pro* which seems to be used by qmake for the generation of the Makefile when I say `configure [options]`. This is suggested to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator) but it does not help. The path does show up neither in the Makefile nor in any call to the compiler.

How can I properly declare my include?

Comment: I recommend asking this in the [Qt forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewforum/14/).

Comment: On Anthony's suggestion, I searched further in the QT forum which led me to [this post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17126/) and further to [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-108) open bug report.

Comment: Finnfalter, did you solve the problem? I have the same problem...

Comment: I did not really solve it, Didac. Instead, I tried to cheat: As I found the 'missing' file in my path, I copied the whole folder in which the file resides into a path known to the compiler (which I determined by looking at -I".." statements of the call to the compiler in the output to the command line). The result was that the compiler found the missing includes but the linker was in lack of the corresponding library. According to [here](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/wiki/DevSetup) You may compile the library by yourself. In practice, I did not succeed to compile it myself so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I finally found the solution (the only difference is that I'm using VS 2008, but I'm using Windows 7, and I needed the 64 bit target as you).

The main problem is that the compressed file that you download from the Qt site is not ok. You have to use what is in the Git repository (currently version 5.0.1, but not the same as the 5.0.1 version that you get from the downloads page)

Here is what I did, step by step, exactly:

prerequisites: have git, perl, python and ruby installed, you have to check your path to see if you can access the executables from anywhere. Search for download links here:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git under "Windows Build environment" section. For Git, download it from here http://git-scm.com

then do the following:

go to the directory where you want to install Qt.

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5

cd qt5

perl init-repository --no-webkit

configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

open a Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt, look for it or for VS 2008 you can execute:
%comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64

inside that window:

```
SET CL=/MP

configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop
```

then press "y" for accepting the licence terms

```
nmake
```

...and that's all.

**Note to the original question:** 
You asked *"How can I properly declare my include?"* and after you explained the way you finally solved it: *"...I copied the whole folder in which the file resides into a path known to the compiler..."*.

Instead of doing that, you might prefer to leave the folder in its original location and do the following before calling nmake:

```
SET CL=/Ic:\MyFolder
```

Note that I used SET CL=/MP before, that's for building faster by using the multiple cores of the processor. So, for that case, you should do:

```
SET CL=/MP /Ic:\MyFolder
```

Answer (score 16):

When migrating form VS2008 to VS2010 (Win7)
I had the same error message regarding "GLES2/gl2.h.

The solution was to add

\include\QtANGLE

to the "AdditionIncludeDirectory" parameter 
in the project properties.

QtANGLE is an alternative to the opengl graphics library as far as I know.

So it seems, that you don't have to build Qt from scratch on windows but you can use the precompiled version. At least not because of the present topic.

Comment: A slight adjustment in Visual Studio 2012 >> add the path to VC++ Directories > "Include Directories".

Comment: Thanks, it worked with my Qt 5.5.1 and VS2015. Have a plus

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem attempting to build qt5.0 and qt5.1 with vs2012.  The problem was simply solved by adding the parameter "-opengl desktop" (no quotes) to the config command and rebuilding (make/nmake/jom/mingw32-make).  I think that all the other stuff mentioned in not necessary to fix you original stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at this link?

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git

> Windows Windows Graphics Drivers
>
> QML2 requires OpenGL 2.1 or higher or Open GL ES 2.0 to work.
>
> In Windows, two options are available:
>
> ```
> Use the ANGLE-library [code.google.com] to translate OpenGL calls into DirectX (default)
> Use the native OpenGL driver for your graphics card
> ```
>
> A copy of ANGLE is bundled in Qt 5. To use Option 1, you need to
>   install the DirectX SDK [msdn.microsoft.com] (Note: Starting from
>   Windows Kit 8, this is included in the Windows SDK).
>
> To use Option 2, you need to ensure that your graphics card driver
>   supports OpenGL 2.1 or higher (Note: The stock Windows driver only
>   supports OpenGL 1.1, which is insufficient), and pass `-opengl
>   desktop’ to configure.exe.

Comment: Thanks t3685, I knew this site. One problem was, that the ANGLE code which came with the bundle did not compile on my machine. Meanwhile, I downloaded ANGLE separately from [here](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/source/checkout) and compiled it succesfully. I then put the compiled sources in a path known to the compiler and enjoyed my compilation.