# Error building Qt for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to build Qt on windows for Visual Studio 2010, so I started following the guide on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010).

However, after running `nmake` I got this error:

[image]

I'm also aware of other threads that relate to this problem, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861718/fatal-error-when-compiling-qt-in-windows) one, that report that has to do with spaces and parentheses in path, so it's better to use short paths, however I don't know well how to do it and I'm afraid of messing up with the path. So, here is my question: considering I have my path such as this:

[image]

Does it mean, for example, that I have to substitute Microsoft SQL Server for MicrosoftSQLServer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to configure Qt with option `-opengl desktop`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing include when compiling QT with Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823253/missing-include-when-compiling-qt-with-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: I've tried to configure with that option but it gives me the same error

Comment: Then, you may want to check the post I referenced in my second comment.