# dbus - how to set include paths

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, dbus

On my system dbus headers are placed in `/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/` and `dbus-arch-deps.h` is other location (what seems to be strange): `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h` In my program I include `#include<dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h>`but in every header file which include others path looks like this: `#include<dbus/xxx.h>` I can copy `dbus-arch-deps.h` to `/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/` but how to fix paths in dbus headers ?

Answer (score 10):

Your system likely has pkg-config installed.

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags dbus-1) main.c
```

Pkgconfig contains a database of linker/compiler/etc. flags that are required to use specific libraries. See `man pkg-config` for more info.

Comment: This worked  for me. But what i don't understand is that why are these package names different?

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to install and configure it properly.
You should try this command :

```
sudo apt-get -y install dbus libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbus-glib-1-dev
```

Now, here is the Makefile that you should write for compiling :

```
all:
g++ dbus.cpp -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 \
    -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include \
    -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
    -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ \
    -ldbus-1 \
    -ldbus-glib-1
```

Now, you may include files like dbus/dbus.h, dbus/dbus-glib.h, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy files.

Simply add the path of where `dbus` is located to your include path when compiling using the `I` flag:

example:

```
g++ -Wall -I /usr/include/dbus-1.0/ -o main.o
```

By using the location of where dbus is located (in the standard location of `/usr/include`, you can reference the files like the following in your source code:

```
#include <dbus/xxx.h>
```

Similarly, if you have to link against `dbus` you'll have to append that path to the Libraries inclusion path like so:

```
g++ -Wall -I /usr/include/dbus-1.0/ -o main.o -L <dbus library path>
```

Where `dbus library path is where the libraries of`dbus` live. To figure this out, consult the web, or search your system.

UPDATE:

To achieve that in Qt-Creator (which I've never used), perhaps the following can help:

[How to add include path in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2752352/866930)

Comment: How to achieve that in Qt Creator ?