# dbus - undefined reference to

Tags: qt, ubuntu-12.04, dbus

This topic is related with following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21602607/dbus-how-to-set-include-paths) . Temporarily I solved problem with headers: I just modified all include paths. When I try to call some dbus function, for example `dbus_error_init(&err);` I get a linker error: **undefined reference to 'dbus_error_init'**. libdbus-1.so is placed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu so I added to pro file  (I use Qt Creator) following line:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -llibdbus-1
```

but I get follwoing info: cannot find -llibdbus-1 How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's just -ldbus-1 or -ldbus. You can also try adding `CONFIG += dbus` in your .pro file to enable the Qt DBUS classes, which if I remember rightly detects the DBUS library as well, as long as Qt was built with support for it.