# Qt DBUS Libraries not loadable if not started from Library-Path

Tags: macos, qt5, dbus, qtdbus

After getting DBUS working on OS X Mavericks after a lot of problems, I have one last problem.
My Apps are not able to interact with the Buses, if i am not in the directory, where libdbus is.

For just making it clear:
The simple program following, that is basically the Widgets-Template, is used for testing:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QDBusConnection con = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
    std::cout << "Connection status " << con.isConnected() << std::endl;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

When running this out of QT Creator, i will get:

```
Connection status 0
```

When moving to my lib-Path (it is /opt/local/lib/; installed dbus via ports), and call /path/to/project/executable, i am getting:

```
Connection status 1
```

So what I have to do to be able to start my app from every location?

Comment: Try to [add include path to QT Creator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2752352/1744123).

Comment: Who is the owner of /opt/local/lib/?