# Linux/CUPS Qt printing example

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cups

I need to use the CUPS API in Qt to detect and install printers. The problem is I can't seem to make Qt detect the cups.h header file. 
So far I tried (both with <> and ""):

```
#include <cups/cups.h>
```

and

```
#include </usr/local/include/cups/cups.h>
```

In the .pro file I also tried adding:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/cups
```

Each time I get "cups/cups.h: no such file or directory". So can anybody provide a minimal example or a HOWTO that shows how to include and use CUPS in a Qt application.

Thanks!

PS: I'am not sure if it's relevant, but I probably should add that I cross compiled Qt for the raspberry Pi.

Comment: Do you actually **have** `/usr/local/include/cups/cups.h` ? Considering that the explicit path apparently fails, it doesn't seem relevant that you use `qmake`. Your C++ compiler just can't find that file.

Comment: /usr/local/include/cups/cups.h exists on my development machine but not on the target (Raspberry Pi). Do I have to cross compile CUPS along with Qt to be able to use it ?

Comment: You must install cups headers in your sysroot, looks like.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the headers to the sysroot worked, but now I get "undefined reference to `cupsGetDefault'...".
I figured out it must be missing a library so I added "LIBS += -lcups" to my project file but it says "can't find -lcups"!

Comment: Libraries are not magic. It's just implementation, i.e. code. And you need to run that code on a RPi, so it better be RPi code. in the library

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add include path in Qt Creator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator)

Comment: @MSalters you were absolutely right ! I was linking to the library in my development machine and not the raspberry one! A quick (find -name "\*cups.so\*") helped me locate the correct Lib. Thanks!

Comment: Why not list printer directly with [Qt Print Support](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-index.html)? It works for me, I can list all printers set up in `cups`.

Answer (score 2):

Install the "libcups2-dev" libraries.

```
 sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
```

then search for the library file

```
find / -type f -name "*.a"
```

you will get the response with all .a library files with the location

find "libcups.a" file from the list.

```
example : /home/Desktop/cups-1.7.5/cups/libcups.a
```

Add the destination file path in your Qt .pro project file

```
LIBS += "../release/build/arm926/libcups.a"
```