# Since Qt3D says Linux is supported, how should I deal with absence of window.h on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt3d

Qt3D has been officially supported by Qt 5.5. They say that [Linux is supported](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html).

I choose an [assimp example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-assimp-example.html), and its [main.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-assimp-main-cpp.html) contains window.h .

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.3. How am I supposed to compile this program?

`No such file or directory` is the error which I am receiving.

[Screenshot of my output in QtCreator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl80w.png)

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? I think you've gotten [window.h](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmacextras-embeddedqwindow-window-h.html) confused with [Windows.h](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx), the latter being available on the Windows platform only.

Comment: could you please add the exact text of your error to your post?

Comment: Ok, I found some info. This file should be in Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\qt3d\common, could you please check do you have this folder and this file in it?

Comment: I think you just need to add appropriate include into your .pro file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window.h` file should be located in `Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\qt3d\common` folder, it doesn't related to Windows, only to `QWindow`.

More details here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/56554/qt-5-5-qt3d-window-h-file-in-the-examples

If this path is not found in your project, you may add this to .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "Qt/Examples/Qt-5.5/qt3d/common"
```

Read more about correct using of include paths in Qt Creator here: [How to add include path in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator)