# How add Boost Library to QTCreator on RPI2?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, boost, raspberry-pi2

I need the boost library for a project on my Raspberry Pi 2. I use QTCreator for coding but I cant add the Library. I tried to add this to the .pro file of my project in QTCreator:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/include/boost -lboost_chrono
```

I installed the boost Library using:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.55-all
```

If I try to compile my code I get the "boost/chrono.hpp no such file or directory". 
I read somewhere that I have to compile the Library first using the same compiler as QtCreator (usually mingw) but I have no clue how to do that.(Im a beginner with the raspberry and the linux system in general)

Thx for your help

Comment: Are you cross compiling or working on the raspberry itself?

Comment: Im working on the raspberry itself. It doesnt matter if it takes long to compile...

Answer (score 0):

```
LIBS += -L
```

This adds a path to the linker. Your error is related to a path in the include. You should add the boost path via

```
INCLUDEPATH +=
```

As mentioned here: [How to add include path in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator#2752396)

Comment: Thx that worked. I also noticed that I tried to include a .hhp instead of a .hpp file^^