# Where to put C++ constants? In a separated/shared header (main.h) file?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I use to put constants like:

```
const QString DATETIME_FORMAT     {"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz"};
```

in a separate file, `main.h`. Actually I put it on a namespace like:

```
namespace projectx {
  const QString DATETIME_FORMAT     {"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz"};
}
```

And then, when I want to use `DATETIME_FORMAT` I have to:

```
#include "../../main.h"
using namespace projectx;
```

Depending on where the file using `main.h` is located the path `../../main.h` change. That's a little annoying.

Is this approach standart? What's the alternative?

Comment: Put them wherever they are needed. Don't expose them where they are not.

Comment: Namespace-scoped `const` objects are `static` by default, so that will put a separate object in each TU that includes your header (which may or may not then be optimized into a single object by the linker). **_Not_** ideal.

Comment: What's the meaning of TU?

Comment: With the given use cases for constant, it seems that constexpr would be a better fit (in c++11 and later) than const and static.

Comment: use -I option in your compiler to avoid "../../etc". `projectx::DATETIME_FORMAT` no need using namespace

Comment: Could you please customize the answer for usage in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative is to use `extern` keyword. Include definition of constant in file `main.cpp`, and external declaration in `main.h`. This approach generate one extra file `main.cpp`, but you have only one instance of constant over all translation units. For example, if you want to include `const int year = 2016` in `project.cpp` (all files in one directory):

```
    $cat main.cpp
    const int year = 2016;
    $cat main.h
    extern const int year;
    $cat project.cpp
    #include "main.h"
    int main()
        {
        ...
    $gcc main.cpp project.cpp -o project -Wall -std=c++11
```

There is one important nuance: if you use straighforward definition `const int year = 2016` in header, multiple inclusions of that file will generate error, but you can declare `extern const int year` many times, and it is valid. You can read more about `extern` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c).

Files located in compiler search path can be included without write down path. In GNU/Linux, if file `main.h` is located in `/usr/include`, then you can include it simply by `#include <main.h>` (more info [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)).

If you want to save `main.h` file path to QT environment, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator) is answer to your question.