# Including external *.cpp and *.h files to prject

Tags: c++, qt

What I have:
(QT ide, qmake, linux)
The project is in C ++. The project needed to use the * .h and * .cpp files that are located in other directories ( "common" library, uncompiled, sources).

How to connect these files to the project (to make some changes in the pro file), specify the path to the "common" library.

Comment: And you want these libs to compile together with your code? Usually it's a better idea to compile them separately and then link them to your project.

Comment: I know that better to compile them separately, but on some reasons i cannot do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator and don't forget to qmake again.