# Installing QMQTT library on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, mqtt

I'm trying to install this module: https://github.com/emqtt/qmqtt 
I put folder in ~/Qt5.9.0/5.9/Src and run:

```
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

But it doesn't work, Qt Creator says:

> 'qmqtt.h' file not found

examples doesn't work either.
I have core, network and mqtt added in my .pro file.

I'm fairly new to Qt, maybe is there something more I should read first?

Comment: Why put it in Qt source? What is your OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add include path in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator)