# Qt: how to include multiple paths and libraries of different types in .pro file

Tags: qt

I want to include multiple paths in the Qt `.pro` file. For example, there are three opencv paths to be included in the file:

```
C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include
C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv
C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv2
```

I have tried (refer to: [INCLUDEPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752352/how-to-add-include-path-in-qt-creator)):

```
INCLUDEPATH = "C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include" "C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv" "C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv2"
```

This puts the three paths quoted and separated by one blank, which seems valid in Qt, but too lengthy for a single line. Is there any other simpler format?

Apart from the path include, I also need to include different types of libraries, some for opencv and other for 1394camera. What I are now doing is:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMU/1394Camera/lib64/x64" -l1394camera -luser32 -L"C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/x64/vc14/lib" -lopencv_core320 -lopencv_imgproc320 -lopencv_highgui320
```

This also puts all the libraries in a single line.

Comment: Use `CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files \(x86)/CMU/1394Camera/lib64/x64" \ -l1394camera \ -luser32 -L"C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/x64/vc14/lib" \ -lopencv_core320 \ -lopencv_imgproc320 \ -lopencv_highgui320`
`

Comment: Can '\' allow to put them in multiple lines?

Comment: yes..........................

Comment: @eyllanesc I have got an error: Extra characters after test expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv2
```

or

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include \
               C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv \
               C:/opencv-3.2.0/mybuild/include/opencv2
```

Please not the `+=` operator, to preserve already set paths.